# YouTube API requests are being recorded that aren't in my code, using 50x more quota than expected

Tags: php, api, youtube

I have a PHP site that contains a database of YouTube channels that sorts the list by most recent video.

Based on my calculations and the calculator on the YouTube API website, to update the list I'm testing with once, which is 22 channels long, it should use up about ~66 quota from the YouTube API, since to find out when a channel's most recent video is you need to call the playlistItems request and set the playlist ID to their channel ID after swapping the second character to a "U". This is three quota, times 22 channels, is 66.

However, to update that list once, I just used 3,073 quota. The YouTube API website says I'm requesting youtube.commentThreads.list, youtube.videos.list, and youtube.search.list (which is really expensive, about 100 quota each) even though they appear nowhere in my code.

[As you can see, the playlistItems number is right at 22, but the others are all random amounts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5tPT.png)

These are the functions used:

```
  public function mostRecentVideo($channelId) {
  $playlistId = substr_replace($channelId, "U", 1, 1);
  $API_URL = $this->base_url . "playlistItems?order=date&part=snippet&playlistId=".$playlistId."&maxResults=1&key=".$this->key;
  $this->videos = json_decode(file_get_contents($API_URL));
  return $this->videos;}

  public function getVideoDate() {
  $videoDate = $this->videos->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;
  $videoDate = str_replace('T', ' ', $videoDate);
  $videoDate = str_replace('Z', '', $videoDate);
  return $videoDate;}

  public function getVideoLink() {
  $videoId = $this->videos->items[0]->snippet->resourceId->videoId;
  $videoLink = "https://youtube.com/watch?v=" . $videoId;
  return $videoLink;}
```

And then this is what's done for every channel in the database, based off the channel ID in there.

```
    $currentChannel = new Search();
    $currentChannel->mostRecentVideo($id);
    $vidDate = $currentChannel->getVideoDate();
    $vidLink = $currentChannel->getVideoLink();
```

Anyone know why this might be happening? With only 10,000 requests per day by default, I'm already flying quite close to the sun and would only be able to update the list once a day. With 3,000 quota being used on just 22 channels, the entire thing becomes infeasible. Thank you

Comment: are you sure nobody else is using your API key? Create a new key, delete the current one and see if the problem persists. Otherwise you may need to contact Google.

Comment: That would be very unlikely, but maybe possible? They only occur when I'm running the script to update the channel database, so if someone else *was* using my API key, they would have to time their requests right when I'm making mine. I purposefully didn't make any requests for about a day to make sure it was all in isolation.

Comment: All right. I don't really know how to help you then. Maybe someone here does. But I recommend you to contact Google about this.

Comment: Are you sure the last code block in your question is not firing youtube.commentThreads.list, youtube.videos.list, and youtube.search.list ? It seems you are filtering video's by channel using `$currentChannel->mostRecentVideo($id);` maybe that's expensive and you should try to find a different way to get the same results?